# When does a city heal after a thermonuclear attack?

Tags: civilization-6

I am playing Civilization 6. I had attacked London with a thermonuclear bomb. It has been at least 100 turns. London is yet to heal itself. So will London heal at all?

PS: London has not been annexed by me, it's still under AI.

Answer (score 1):

The city does not need to heal per se. After a nuclear attack or accident, tiles owned by the city or affected by the attack are contaminated with [Nuclear Fallout](https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Nuclear_weapons_(Civ6)#Nuclear_Fallout). This effect does not decay normally, that is, I have never see it happen. Instead, you need to clear the damage by using a builder or similar unit with a charge such as a Military Engineer, Toa, or Roman Legion.

While affected by Nuclear Fallout, tiles cannot be worked but the city does function normally with its remaining tiles working as intended. While the city has likely lost a lot of population, if it can work enough food and production to repair districts and grow, it will prosper even without clearing the Nuclear Fallout.

Comment: By heal I mean the city's defense modifier is at 0. So even an ancient warrior can easily capture it

Comment: You should focus your question, that wasn't clear at all from what you wrote. City health and city strength are two very different things. Also, please include a screenshot, it will help bring your point across and possible answers to be clear and concise.